# Wordpress Form custom field

Tags: wordpress

I have created a form using wordpress which returns the title and description. I need to return a few more custom fields. I have searched the internet and found many answers which did not explain it very well and they did not end up working for me. The form would return a post with title, description, the custom fields already filled in. Thanks!

if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

```
// Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
    $title =  $_POST['title'];
} else {
    echo 'Please enter the wine name';
}
if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
    $description = $_POST['description'];
} else {
    echo 'Please enter some notes';
}


// ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
$new_post = array(
'post_title'    =>  $title,
'post_content'  =>  $description,
'post_Blog_URL' => $URL,  
'post_status'   =>  'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
'post_type' =>  'post'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
);

add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, 'URL' , $unique); 

//SAVE THE POST
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

//REDIRECT TO THE NEW POST ON SAVE
$link = get_permalink( $pid );
wp_redirect( $link );
```

} // END THE IF STATEMENT THAT STARTED THE WHOLE FORM

do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');

### Submit your own!

```
                <div id="postbox">

                <form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" class="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <!-- post name -->
                <fieldset name="name">
                    <label>Name of the Article</label>
                    <input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="title" />
                </fieldset>   


                <!-- post Content -->
                <fieldset class="content">
                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                    <textarea id="description" tabindex="15" name="description"></textarea>
                </fieldset>


                <button type="submit">Submit</button>

                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />

                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>

                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to show Post Meta Fields in your form.

There are a few functions to set, update and retrieve these which will be helpful:

[get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) or [get_post_custom](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom)

[add_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta)

[update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)

With those functions, you can create any kind of meta information for posts and display them either in the admin panel or to the end user, depending on the scenario.

Comment: Yes ive looked up all those functions, i have problems in the implementation. Situation: A sser from the front end will submit a field through a custom form and then i need it to be entered into the post, into the custom field. Do i need to alter my functions? or just the post php?

Comment: You would need to use WordPress hooks to have it call those functions when the form saves. Your PHP shows that it is already doing this with the URL meta. You more or less just want to extend what that is doing to add new fields.

Comment: precisely, im just unsure how to do it. description and title are already built into wordpress